# PHP:: Fully-qualified method literal to string

Tags: php, string, class, methods, literals

Essentially, I seek to pass a static class method to a callback, but do not wish to do so using a hard-coded string, but rather the fully-qualified class method literal. We can do that using classes like so:

```
$name = NS\FooClass::class;
```

instead of:

```
$name = 'NS\FooClass';
```

which will give us the string of the fully-qualified name of the class. I seek to be able to do something similar for a class method like so:

```
$name = NS\FooClass::foo_method::method;
```

instead of:

```
$name = 'NS\FooClass::foo_method';
```

It is more manageable and I can use the IDE functionality way better using the literals. Any similar way I can achieve what I want with the class methods without using strings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**As of PHP 8.1**, the language has support for ["first class callables"](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.first_class_callable_syntax.php) using the syntax `method_or_function(...)`, so in this case:

```
$callback = FooClass::foo_method(...);
```

This has the same effect as the older [Closure::fromCallable](https://www.php.net/manual/en/closure.fromcallable.php) method: it creates a `Closure` object, like an anonymous function, referring to the referenced method. This can then be used anywhere that a "callable" is expected, instead of specifying the name or an array format.

The class and method are checked and expanded in exactly the same way as if you were calling the method immediately - e.g. the current `namespace` and `use` statements are taken into account, and the resulting method must actually exist.

---

For older versions, or some use cases where you *want* to be able to work with strings, [the manual page on the `callable` type](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php) gives two ways to specify a static method for use as a callback:

- As a string, as in your example `'NS\FooClass::foo_method'`
- As an array where the first part is a class name, and the second part is a the method name: `['NS\FooClass', 'foo_method']`

Since only the class name needs to be qualified with namespace information, you can use `::class` with the second syntax to get nearly what you wanted:

```
$callback = [NS\FooClass::class, 'foo_method'];
```

This allows any decent IDE to spot the reference to the class, and allows you to reference it by [an imported or aliased name](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php).

It's worth noting that if the `callable` type is specified in a parameter or return type declaration or a docblock, some IDEs (e.g. PhpStorm) will "understand" either format as a reference to the method, and include it in features like "find usages" and "go to declaration".

Comment: Excellent answer! Single statement answering the question, followed by a very elaborate explanation as well as work-arounds. Thank you very much!

Comment: Excellent answer about a very mediocre design

Comment: @AntonDuzenko Actually, the answer was out of date! See new section at the top about support added in PHP 8.1.